# none of my drawings/animations on canvas show up

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm following a tutorial on using vanilla JS/HTML/CSS to create a 2D animation game. I'm currently stuck, however, because none of my 'drawings' or animations seem to show up on my canvas. I've checked that the script.js was linked correctly, and when I "inspect" the page, the variables & functions are all defined and console.log works perfectly—so script.js itself seems to be linked, and non-animation or drawing related JS seems to work fine.

I've also tried clearing my cache and tried using stuff like codepen.io to check if my browser (Chrome) was faulty, but none of these work. Then I checked the ran the snipper I pasted here, which seems to work sometimes. The only reason why I don't think Chrome is an issue here is because when I run my previous projects with animations/drawings, they work fine.

Could someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

let ravens = [];
class Raven {
    constructor() {
        this.width = 100;
        this.height = 50;
        this.x = canvas.width;
        this.y = Math.random() * (canvas.height - this.height);
        this.directionX = Math.random() * 5 + 3;
        this.directionY = Math.random() * 5 - 2.5;
    }
    update() {
        this.x -= this.directionX;
    }
    draw() {
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
}

const raven = new Raven();

function animate(timestamp) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    raven.update();
    raven.draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();
```

```css
body {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, DarkTurquoise, DarkMagenta, DeepPink, rgb(255, 129, 71));
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
    /* background: HotPink; */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Point and Shoot</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas1">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </canvas>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have seen the black rectangle going left, is that what should happen?

Comment: yes! but if I run the code snippet here many times, it doesn't seem to always happen. (and the rectangle never shows up on my chrome)

Comment: When i log the raven object to console, I see that sometimes its y coordinate is negative

Comment: This `Math.random() * 5 - 2.5` can be between `-2.5` and `2.5` and canvas starts at `0`

Comment: I see, so you mean that when it's negative it won't show up on my canvas. But even when I get rid of the negative and just do something like Math.random()*5, I don't get any rectangles showing up

Comment: try this `this.y = 100` then you will see your raven object

Comment: oh wow, thank you! But I did want to have some kind of randomness to where the y coordinate would be, and apparently `Math.random() * (canvas.height - this.height)` isn't the correct way to go. Do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: this.y = Math.random() * canvas.height; dont use the width on the y axis

Comment: Whoops, I had a typo—I meant (canvas.height - this.height) originally, which doesn't work, and unfortuantely this.y = Math.random() * canvas.height doesn't seem to work on chrome still.

Comment: Your updated snippet seems working to me

Comment: fixed things now, thank you so much everyone!